# OpenGL - Is it possible to use texture buffers with interleaved VBOs?

Tags: opengl, buffer, textures, vbo

Is there a method for binding only a single attribute of a VBO to a texture buffer object?

Problem is, I use an **interleaved VBO** for drawing spheres with the attributes position, radius and another one. Now, I want to use another shader which draws other stuff using **instanced geometry** at the positions in my sphere VBO.
What I could do is just texelFetch() the data I need which is really ugly concerning the needed alignment (VBO attributes have different size) and the unused space, which is bad because of the limited size of a texture buffer. Another way could be copying only the data I need from one VBO to a separate VBO, but that's not really satisfying either.

So... is there another possibility?

Comment: *"and the unused space, which is bad because of the limited size of a texture buffer."* - Huh? You know that a texture buffer doesn't take any additional memory, it's just a pointer to the buffer data (whose complete data you already *need* to store). And likewise I don't think a texture buffer has any significant size limitation compared to the underlying buffer object, it can be at least 2^27 texels large, which would be some 8 million vertices *if using 16 attributes* (which I guess you don't).

Comment: yes, i did know that it doesn't take additional memory but i didn't know the actual minimum size of a texture buffer object.

Comment: I got this number from the `ARB_texture_buffer` extension, but would really wonder if the core version limited that further. Their size is in fact *one* of their advantages over ordinary 1D textures (and also uniform buffers, I think).

Comment: Hmm, wait a minute, strangely enough the OpenGL 3.3 specification lists only 64k as the minimum supported max texture buffer size, while the EXT_texture_buffer_object extension said something about 2^27 (but then also listing 64k as minimum value). I guess 64k is the theoretical limit to be supported while the 2^27 is the practical limit at the time of its introduction.

Answer (score 1):

[Buffer textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) do not have *attributes*. So what you're talking about doesn't make sense.

Also, VBOs are not a thing; there is no such thing as a "VBO". There are simply [buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object) and different uses for them. `glVertexAttribPointer` does not modify the buffer object. It just tells OpenGL's vertex reading system how to fetch data from it. Other systems that fetch data from buffer objects use their own mechanisms for doing so, which are entirely separate.

Like buffer textures.

If you want to "draws other stuff using instanced geometry", why don't you just [use *instancing*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Instanced_arrays)? Apply a divisor (presumably of 1) to those attributes, so that they will only get different values for different instances.

Comment: glVertexAttribDivisor looks like the function i was looking for, but i don't really get how to use it. I have two vertex buffer objects: #1 with the vertex data for the geometry to draw and #2 for the instance attributes like position. So what i think i should do is just declare the attributes of #1 without divisor and the ones from #2 with divisor and add the locations in the shader. Is that correct? And I dont need a texture buffer object?

Comment: and I didn't say, that buffer textures have attributes. I just wanted to bind the data of a single attribute from another buffer object to a texture buffer object. I might have been not very clear.

Comment: @maumau: "*So what i think i should do is just declare the attributes of #1 without divisor and the ones from #2 with divisor and add the locations in the shader.*" First, that's a completely new question. You asked about buffer textures and interleaved data. If you have a question about how to use instanced arrays, you would ask with the "Ask question" button. Second, yes, that's the general idea. And yes, you wouldn't be using a buffer texture.